# Exporting Aws credentials

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I'm following this tutorial to upload a nodejs app with the aws-sdk into beanstalk.

http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/nodejs/

However I don't understand this step:

```
Configure the Access Keys
Export your access keys to environment variables and replace the ellipses (...) with your access keys:
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="..."

export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="..."
```

Help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have received two long magic numbers when you set up your account. They are the identifiers you use to access resources on AWS and must be kept secret.

You can get the ACCESS_KEY_ID from your Amazon account [here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential), but you can't get the secret access key any more. You should have recorded that somewhere safe when the account was set up. You can create a new one though, by looking under `Access Keys` on that page.

The instructions show you how to get those identifier numbers into environment variables so that subsequent commands know which account to connect to. Run the commands in an ssh session by replacing the ellipsis with the two keys. This will set the environment variables and the following commands should access your account.

For example:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="DSFGHGTHYJKRTERTE/"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="DETHRTYJDGTYJ%HFR%HFTHJJJ"
node sample.js
```

Comment: I write git aws.push on the command line to upload my app to beanstalk (rather then ssh).  If in my access keys are stored in my .elasticbeanstalk/aws_credential_file, would that be the same thing as the export way?